# How to Assign new name for every downloaded pdf from url in Objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, download

I have a code which download pdf from url..but every time I download url on button click it replace old pdf with new downloaded pdf with the same name.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"https://www.clickdimensions.com/links/TestPDFfile.pdf";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
{
  NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  

  NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.pdf"];
  [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

1. I want to download pdf in the phone locel download folder
2. when user again click on the download pdf button the same pdf should be downloaded with the name filename(2).pdf it should not replace the first one

Comment: Check if file exists with default name then loop on new names like pdfname-(<integer value>) starting with 2, until you find an non existing name.

Comment: @PtitXav I am not very good with objc..can you please explain through code ??

Comment: Does it need to have a human readable name? Or does it just have to be unique? If the latter, just use a UUID for the name of the file.

Comment: @Sarthak something like : [NSFileManager.defaultManager fileExistAtPath:filePath]

Comment: @PtitXav can you please make edit in my existing code ...as i am not getting you completely..because I am very beginner in objc.......I created 2 function (func1 & func2) added above code in both function and used 2 different url to download pdf in both func..and called both function in viewDidLoad...and when I checked for pdf on that path in both function....IO am getting only 1 pdf there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking to something like :

```
    NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.pdf"];
    int fileCopyNum = 1;
    // Loop until available file name is found
    while ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        // compute a new file name by incrementing index
        // first new file name will start at 1++ = 2
        fileCopyNum++;
        filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@-(%d).pdf", documentsDirectory,@"filename", fileCopyNum];
    }
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```